# Why is my iFrame HTML file not being shown inline? Instead, the HTML file is being downloaded

Tags: html, iframe, inline, content-disposition

Up until a few weeks ago, any HTML files I linked to an iFrame would be shown within the frame. All of a sudden, Chrome and Firefox will now ask me whether I want to download the HTML file in the iFrame. It's an Apache server and I do believe it was upgraded recently. How it was upgraded, I am not sure. I was wondering if it had anything to do with the way certain MIME types get processed within an iFrame.

Note: Chrome and Firefox are the only browsers that I've tested this with. I don't think this is a browser issue though.

Comment: So basically, nothing's changed, except the entire server got modified... that'll help narrow things down.

Comment: Can you show us the place where this happens or elaborate a bit with an code example?

Comment: What happens if you open the iframe url in the addres bar in a normal tab? Also, can you check the developer tools of the browser (Network tab) to see what Content-Type header the iframe response has?

Comment: try to remove content disposition header response from server

Comment: The second answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144554/set-change-mime-type-of-iframe might be useful, it sounds like a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely the mime-type configuration is no longer properly set up on your Apache server. Most of the time, the server configuration sets the mime type of the returned object based on the file extension you're requesting. If your file extensions have changed, or if you're using dynamic URLs that don't end in ".docx"), e.g. that get processed by an intervening app server to return the file without themselves setting the MIME type, then the browser has no way of knowing what the contents are, and correctly concludes that the best thing to do is to just gives you the contents in a file.

So... set the extension of the file you're downloading to .docx or .doc. If you're using a default Apache config, that might do it. If that doesn't work, change the mime type of the returned object based on a URL filter configuration in your apache.conf or other apache config file. Or if using dynamic URLs, explicitly set the mime type in your code to one of the following:

```
.doc - application/msword
.dot - application/msword
.docx - application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
.dotx - application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template
.docm - application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12
.dotm - application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12
```